# Most likely configuration of coins flips given their value

Tags: probability, statistics, puzzle

Suppose I have 500 silver coins and 500 gold coins, and all are fair. If a heads on a silver coin gives me 1 dollar, and a heads on a gold coin gives me 3 dollars. Then we know the expected number of dollars received after flipping all 1000 coins is $1\cdot250 + 3\cdot250=1000$.

**The question:** Suppose I flipped all the coins and got 1100 dollars. What is the most likely configurations of the number of silvers and number of golds?

**Thoughts:** I know there are many possible ways this could happen. The extra \$100 outside of the expected 1000 could come from, say, 100 extra silver heads, or 33 golds and 1 silver. Intuitively, both of these configurations are unlikely because there is only way of scoring 100 extra silvers, e.g. So something in between all silvers and (almost) all golds should be more likely.

I could brute force this problem by using the binomial distribution to calculate the probability of any number of heads:
$P(k \text{ heads}) = (500 \text{ choose } k)\left(\frac12\right)^{500} $. So we could find the probability of any configuration ($j$ silver heads, $k$ gold heads). But I would have to plug in every possible combination that adds up to 100.

Note: this was an interview question, and was meant to be solved intuitively rather than with equations.

Comment: Well, you want both numbers to be as close to $250$ as possible so it's "cheaper" to add a few gold Heads.  See how close you can get that way.  I see two good candidates, not sure if one is better than the other.

Comment: @lulu is it as simple as making the two numbers as close to 250 as possible? And why not make the total number of heads (gold + silver) as small as possible? That would simply be 33 golds and 1 silver

Comment: Why $33$?  Minimal number would be $366$ gold and $2$ silver.  But both of those outcomes are wildly improbable.

Comment: I checked in detail:  the optimal one is indeed one of the two I figured.  The two methods gave similar answers...one was to minimize the sum of squared distance from $250$ and the other was to minimize the absolute difference.  Of course, you really want to minimize a binomial symbol but that's hard to do intuitively.  I don't know why squared distance works better...like I say, the answers are very close.

Comment: Usually in interview questions, the interviewer wants to see a solid method of attack.  Here, barring some inside into the decay rates of binomial coefficients, I don't see a quick and easy way to nail the answer down exactly, but I described is fast and easy and comes very close (hits it exactly if you use least squares).

Comment: My initial take was that an extra $~25~$ of each was a strong contender, because my intuition (which could be wrong) is that the decay rates of the binomial coefficients increases at the end points.  So, this would rule out $~100~$ extra silver coins.  However, each added gold coin allows you to retract $~3~$ added silver coins.  So, my guess is that you want somewhere between $~25~$ and $~33~$ extra gold coins.  If I had to guess, I would estimate that you want somewhere between $~28~$ and $~30~$ extra gold coins.

Comment: It's a mistake, I believe, to look at all the coins and ignore the split between gold and silver.  For instance, say the value were $1500$ instead of $1100$.  Then you could get that with exactly $500$ heads (the most likely total for all the coins) provided all the gold ones came up $H$ and all the silver ones came up $T$.  But that's an inconceivably unlikely occurence.

Comment: @lulu interesting that you thought to minimize the squared distance. Why? Is that something that comes up in probability or more specifically the binomial distribution?

Comment: @900edges. Not really.  Just needed a definition of "closest".  Like I say,  it also did it by minimizing absolute difference.  That yields a slightly worse result.

Comment: @900edges  To be sure, it might be a coincidence that it is exact in this case.  My only thought had been that it was sure to be close.

Answer (score 2):

Let $N_S$, $N_G$ denote independent binomial random variables with parameters $(500,\frac 12)$.
You want to maximize the conditional probability $$P(N_S=i, N_G=j|N_S+3N_G=1100)$$
over $0\leq i,j\leq 500.$

This quantity is proportional to
$$\binom{500}{i}\binom{500}{j} 1_{i+3j= 1100},$$
hence it suffices to maximize
$$a_j:=\binom{500}{1100-3j}\binom{500}{j} ,$$
where $200\leq j\leq 366$.

By analyzing the ratio $a_{j+1}/a_j$, we see that $a_j$ is maximal for $j=280$, hence $i=260$.

Thus the most probable configuration is $260$ silver coins and $280$ gold coins.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can you explain your statement "This quantity is proportional to..."? And how does the bound $200 \leq j \leq 366$ affect the optimization problem?

Comment: @900edges there is a constant $C$ such that for every $i,j$ we have $$P(N_S=i, N_G=j|N_S+3N_G=1100) = C \binom{500}{i}\binom{500}{j} 1_{i+3j= 1100}.$$ The constraint $200\leq j\leq 366$ stems from $0\leq 1100-3j\leq 500$.